# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.apache.activemq.util.IdGenerator

Tags: activemq-classic, soapui

I am trying to use `ActiveMQ 5.10.0` with `SoapUI 4.6` and `Hermes 1.14`. I get the error below when I try and add a queue. I presume Hermes can't find the type `IdGenerator` in any of the loaded jars. Which are:

```
activemq-client-5.10.0.jar
geronimo-j2ee-management_1.1_spec-1.0.1.jar
geronimo-jms_1.1_spec-1.1.1.jar
```

Does anyone know where this class is defined? I looked for `activemq-util.jar` in the binary distribution but I did not find such a file.

**Error:**

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.apache.activemq.util.IdGenerator 
        at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory.getClientIdGenerator(ActiveMQConnectionFactory.java:969) 
        at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory.createActiveMQConnection(ActiveMQConnectionFactory.java:363) 
        at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory.createActiveMQConnection(ActiveMQConnectionFactory.java:331) 
        at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory.createActiveMQConnection(ActiveMQConnectionFactory.java:303) 
        at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory.createQueueConnection(ActiveMQConnectionFactory.java:260) 
        at hermes.impl.jms.ConnectionManagerSupport.createConnection(ConnectionManagerSupport.java:147) 
        at hermes.impl.jms.ConnectionManagerSupport.createConnection(ConnectionManagerSupport.java:92) 
        at hermes.impl.jms.ConnectionSharedManager.reconnect(ConnectionSharedManager.java:81) 
        at hermes.impl.jms.ConnectionSharedManager.connect(ConnectionSharedManager.java:91) 
        at hermes.impl.jms.ConnectionSharedManager.getConnection(ConnectionSharedManager.java:104) 
        at hermes.impl.jms.ConnectionSharedManager.getObject(ConnectionSharedManager.java:142) 
        at hermes.impl.jms.ThreadLocalSessionManager.connect(ThreadLocalSessionManager.java:190) 
        at hermes.impl.jms.ThreadLocalSessionManager.getSession(ThreadLocalSessionManager.java:570) 
        at hermes.impl.jms.AbstractSessionManager.getDestination(AbstractSessionManager.java:460) 
        at hermes.impl.DefaultHermesImpl.getDestination(DefaultHermesImpl.java:367) 
        at hermes.browser.tasks.BrowseDestinationTask.invoke(BrowseDestinationTask.java:141) 
        at hermes.browser.tasks.TaskSupport.run(TaskSupport.java:175) 
        at hermes.browser.tasks.ThreadPool.run(ThreadPool.java:170) 
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The IdGenerator class is located in the activemq-client jar.  Here is the result of a search in the source tree:

> /activemq-client/src/main/java/org/apache/activemq/util/IdGenerator.java

There's been no recent changes so I'd guess that the error is misleading and that it's actually some other missing dependency that's being loaded when the class is created.  Is there more information in the log or a 'caused by exception' ?

Comment: Thanks, do you know if the namespace has changed or if it was moved since ActiveMq 5.4? SoapUi seems to have trouble finding it even thought the activemq-client jar is included

Comment: Please mark as resolved as the stated question is answered.  Ask additional questions as needed.

Answer (score 4):

This is very old but in case anyone else is trying to get this spun up... don't use the built in HermesJMS that comes with SoapUI. Apparently there's a bug in it that doesn't play nice with ActiveMQ v5.8 and following [I tried 5.11 & 5.13 and had the issue. The cheating fix is to install the standalone [I had to get it from sourceforge].

The sourceforge jar is installed with [assuming version 1.14]: java -jar hermes-installer-1.14.jar

Once installed you can tie this version to soapui or launch it with the bat/sh file. I still had issues with ActiveMQ version 5.13 but version 5.11 worked for me.

Comment: Thanks, will try this method out

Comment: Notice that if you use a recent Java version(>=Java8) you also have to customize some config as denoted in this answer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/36565755/15619

Answer (score 1):

For whom it may interest. This is kind of common issue I come accross from time to time. I call it jar version incompatibility. I was getting exception in title and other funny exceptions when using latest (but not actively developed) hermes 1.14 and currently latest Apache Active MQ 5.14. I've found out after a long struggle that it is fixed by using an older version of Active MQ - like 5.3.