# Trying to configure Hermes JMS for ActiveMQ. Error is thrown when Queue is browsed

Tags: jms, activemq-classic, soapui

Following is what I have done:

1. Created a new session in HermesJMS
2. Following is the configuration:

   [image]
3. In the Loader Group following are the added JARs:

   i. `activemq-all-5.11.1.jar`

   ii. `geronimo-j2ee-management_1.1_spec-1.0.1.jar`

Here is what I am able to do:

1. I am able to create a queue Publish/consume messages from the queue
2. I can browse and check the message at http://localhost:8161/admin/browse.jsp?JMSDestination=Q1

Following is the problem I am facing:

1. When I browse any Queue in HermesJMS, I get following error:

   ```
   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.apache.activemq.util.IdGenerator
       at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory.getClientIdGenerator(ActiveMQConnectionFactory.java:910)
       at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQXAConnectionFactory.createActiveMQConnection(ActiveMQXAConnectionFactory.java:84)
       at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory.createActiveMQConnection(ActiveMQConnectionFactory.java:274)
       at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory.createActiveMQConnection(ActiveMQConnectionFactory.java:246)
       at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory.createConnection(ActiveMQConnectionFactory.java:186)
       at hermes.impl.jms.ConnectionManagerSupport.createConnection(ConnectionManagerSupport.java:122)
       at hermes.impl.jms.ConnectionManagerSupport.createConnection(ConnectionManagerSupport.java:92)
       at hermes.impl.jms.ConnectionSharedManager.reconnect(ConnectionSharedManager.java:81)
       at hermes.impl.jms.ConnectionSharedManager.connect(ConnectionSharedManager.java:91)
       at hermes.impl.jms.ConnectionSharedManager.getConnection(ConnectionSharedManager.java:104)
       at hermes.impl.jms.ConnectionSharedManager.getObject(ConnectionSharedManager.java:142)
       at hermes.impl.jms.ThreadLocalSessionManager.connect(ThreadLocalSessionManager.java:190)
       at hermes.impl.jms.ThreadLocalSessionManager.getSession(ThreadLocalSessionManager.java:570)
       at hermes.impl.jms.AbstractSessionManager.getDestination(AbstractSessionManager.java:460)
       at hermes.impl.DefaultHermesImpl.getDestination(DefaultHermesImpl.java:367)
       at hermes.browser.tasks.BrowseDestinationTask.invoke(BrowseDestinationTask.java:141)
       at hermes.browser.tasks.TaskSupport.run(TaskSupport.java:175)
       at hermes.browser.tasks.ThreadPool.run(ThreadPool.java:170)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
   ```

I have also tried changing Class at connection factory to `org.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory` and got the same error

Also tried adding activemq-client.jar to the loader group but no change in error.

PS: Tried using ActiveMQ version 5.11.1 and 5.9.0

I need to configure the sessions in HermesJMS so that I can use SoapUI support for JMS.

Comment: Please see this [link](http://community.smartbear.com/t5/SoapUI-NG/Resolved-soapui-pro-amp-HermesJMS-integration/td-p/38034), looks there is an issue.

Comment: @Rao Is there any alternative for this.

Comment: Just happened to find that link. No, never used activeMQ.

Comment: Are you sure that you typed in the package right for ActiveMQConnectionFactory? It should be org.apache.activemq.

Comment: I am afraid @JakubKorab that I could not understand what you are referring to. If you are taking about Class in Connection factory, so, I have also tried using `org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory` from the dropdown on Preferences window.

Comment: If you are not stuck with HermesJMS, you can give a try to JMSToolBox on sourceforge that should be way easier to configure (BTW I'm the author of JMSToolBox)

Comment: This [stackoveflow response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25030146/java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-could-not-initialize-class-org-apache-activemq-u/43226704/#answer-36901511) solved my issue.